# MySQL Stored procedure overrides empty parameters

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a Stored Procedure to generate some reports in csv. The signature is as follow:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testSP (IN filename VARCHAR(100),
             IN study VARCHAR(100))
```

The SP creates a query with a conditional WHERE clause based on the 'study' input parameter.

```
DECLARE studyFilter TEXT DEFAULT '';

  IF (study IS NOT NULL AND study != '') THEN
    SET @studyFilter = CONCAT(' AND st.goid like \'%',study,'%\' ');
  END IF;
```

This run well if I call the SP with a not empty study parameter, eg.g

```
call testSP('/tmp/test.csv','study1');
```

But if I call the SP with an empty study, instead of having an empty parameters the SP uses the last values of study.

e.g. if I call, in sequence
    call testSP('/tmp/test1.csv','study1');

```
call testSP('/tmp/test2.csv','');
```

The second time the value of the parameter is still 'study1' and so the query has an incorrect WHERE clause.

How is this possible? how could I correctly reset that parameter value? I'm using MySQL 6.1 and MySQL Workbench to test the SP. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@studyFilter` is valid for the whole session, but only gets modified if the condition is true. That's why it keeps the previous result if the the condition is false. Initialize it to `NULL` or to `an empty string`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok find it out, I was using session variables @studyFilter while I should have used a local variable studyFilter

changing the code to the following worked:

```
DECLARE studyFilter TEXT DEFAULT '';    
IF (study IS NOT NULL AND study != '') THEN
   SET studyFilter = CONCAT(' AND st.goid like \'%',study,'%\' ');
END IF;
```